# Unity Vector3 Slerp on wanted axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, interpolation

Hi I'm making a little 3D platformer with a player controller like zelda/mario64.
I want to add the possibility to reset the camera behind the player. It ok, not really hard, but I wanted to do this smoothly and with the camera rotating around the player.
I discovered the `Slerp` method of `Vector3` that almost do what I want. But I don't know if it's possible to force the Slerp method to make a trajectory only on the x,z plan. I dont want the camera to go above the player but turn arround it.

- Someone know of it's possible to `Vector3.Slerp()` only on some axis ?
- Or maybe `Vector3.Slerp()` is not the solution, so what can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your looking for `Transform.localEulerAngles` (you can find out more about it [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html)). What I would do in your situation is keep the axis you don't want to move and use Slerp on this other(s) :

```
Vector3 currentLocalEulerAngles = transform.localEulerAngles;
Vector3 targetLocalEulerAngles = /*What you want*/ Vector3.zero;
float slerpSpeed;
transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(transform.localEulerAngles, new Vector3(currentLocalEulerAngles.x, targetLocalEulerAngles.y, targetLocalEulerAngles.z), slerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

**EDIT :** To be clear I suggested this way of doing things having in mind that in those kind of situations, the *Camera* is often placed as a child of a *GameObject* located **on** the player. This way you simply have to rotate what can be called the *CameraHolder* : ***Player*** (doing what you want) > ***CameraHolder*** (rotating along local axis) > ***Camera*** (fixed or getting shaked or what you want) :)

**EDIT2 :** Here's a small script that will do what you're looking for (hopefully) : you simply have to set your ***Camera*** as child of your *Player*, place it so it "looks" at your *Player* with desired distance/angle, and finally add this ***CameraHolder*** script to your ***Camera***.

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class CameraHolder : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0.0f, 10.0f)]
    [SerializeField]
    private float m_CameraResetSpeed = 4.0f;

    [Range(0.0f, 10.0f)]
    [SerializeField]
    private float m_MinAngleToStopReseting = 2.0f;

    private Transform m_CameraHolderTransform;
    private Vector3 m_CameraHolderWorldEulerAngles;
    private bool m_ResetingCamera;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject cameraHolder = new GameObject("CameraHolder");
        m_CameraHolderTransform = cameraHolder.transform;
        m_CameraHolderTransform.SetParent(transform.parent);
        m_CameraHolderTransform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        m_CameraHolderTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        m_CameraHolderTransform.localScale = Vector3.one;

        transform.SetParent(cameraHolder.transform);

        m_CameraHolderWorldEulerAngles = m_CameraHolderTransform.eulerAngles;

        m_ResetingCamera = false;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if(m_ResetingCamera)
        {
            m_CameraHolderTransform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0.0f,
                Mathf.LerpAngle(m_CameraHolderTransform.localEulerAngles.y, 0.0f, m_CameraResetSpeed * Time.deltaTime), 0.0f);

            if(Mathf.Abs(m_CameraHolderTransform.localEulerAngles.y) < m_MinAngleToStopReseting)
            {
                Debug.Log("Reset done...");
                m_ResetingCamera = false;
                m_CameraHolderWorldEulerAngles = m_CameraHolderTransform.eulerAngles;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            m_CameraHolderTransform.eulerAngles = m_CameraHolderWorldEulerAngles;
        }
    }

    public void ResetCamera()
    {
        Debug.Log("Reseting camera...");
        m_ResetingCamera = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you may have misjudged the OP's intentions here - it sounds like the desire is to rotate the camera around a point (the player position), not just in-place around its own axis.

Comment: @Serlite You pointed out what I forgot to add to my answer... (In my mind it was very clear but I forgot to add it). I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Kardux The behaviour I want is exactly that : [demo gif](http://gph.is/2gVkmZe). A smooth rotation of the camera around the player, only on the xz plan, to reset camera behind.

Comment: @PaulSenon Please find an updated answer : I added a script that will achieve the effect your looking for (simply call the `ResetCamera()` method when needed).